# How can I access a 'Web App' built in Google Apps Script from Android?

Tags: java, android, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I can successfully access Google Drive and Spreadsheet functionality from my application.

So I have an authorised instance of com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.

Now I wish to execute a Google Apps Script that is deployed as a 'Web App'. This will also require authentication to run. This script runs in the browser if I hit the endpoint and am authenticated.

Here's some psuedo code :

```
String url = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/mycompany.com/s/xxxx/dev";
GenericUrl webAppEndPoint = new GenericUrl(url);
final HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(currentCredential);

// Do POST for service

String requestBody = URLEncoder.encode("{\"name\":\"John Smith\",\"company\":\"Virginia Company\",\"pdf\":\""+getPdfBase64()+"\"}", "UTF-8");
HttpRequest postRequest =requestFactory.buildPostRequest(new GenericUrl(url), ByteArrayContent.fromString(null, requestBody));
postRequest.getHeaders().setAccept("application/json");
postRequest.setFollowRedirects(true);
postRequest.setLoggingEnabled(true);
HttpResponse postResponse = postRequest.execute();
```

If I run the code I get the following error : com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: HttpResponseException 405 Method Not Allowed

UPDATE : So - originally i was POSTing to the wrong URL ( i'd copied the redirected URL from a browser instead of the script URL )

The POST is now successful ( authentication included ) using the above code, but it still doesn't handle the GET redirect after submission. I can work with this now but it would be good to be able to get a response from the server.

I think that com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest doesn't handle authenticated POST redirects properly.

Comment: So this seems to shed some light on the issue -https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2707 - the POST redirects and becomes a GET

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode isn’t very illuminating; to really see what’s going on you’d need to show the actual HTTP traffic.  I should say though that a 302 redirect to a specified redict_uri is a normal part of the OAuth 2 authentication flow.

Comment: Tim, example definitely works now, but the redirect still not handled. As a GET, redirect works fine and the script can return a result.

Answer (score 0):

1) you cant call an apps script with authentication. You need to publish it as anonymous access as a contentService.
2)you are also calling the wrong url. Call the service url not the redirected one that you get in the browser.

Comment: Zig, You were right about the service URL (doh! updated) - but the authentication works, it just doesn't seem to handle the redirect after submission.

Comment: your url is still wrong, you are using the debug url instead of the real one. Also, see if publishing as anonymous access fixes anything.

Comment: Zig, just using that as i'm developing the script at the moment - doesn't seem to make any difference to the result - it always wants to redirect after submission. The POST all submitting ok now but the redirection not being handled properly by the HttpRequest. TBH - now its submitting I can work around this.